# mongodb -- count() much slower than find()?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using mongoose to count the number of documents that match a certain query. My index for this query is: `{createdAt: -1, status: -1, oId: -1}`

Mongo version is 3.2, amount of docs in the collection is about 1.75 million.

If I do:

```js
model.find({
                        createdAt: {'$gte': threeMonths, '$lt': today},
                        status: {'$in': model.STATUS_SET}
                    }).select({_id: 0, status: 1}).count().then((c) => result[alias] = c)
```

It takes more than 2 minutes. But if I do:

```js
model.find({
                createdAt: {'$gte': threeMonths, '$lt': today},
                status: {'$in': model.STATUS_SET}
            }).select({_id: 0, status: 1}).lean().then((c) => result[alias] = c.length)
```

then it takes about 2.5 seconds.

Something I'm doing wrong? Something I can do to help speed things up?

EDIT: Explain logs.

For count:

```js
"executionStats" : {
  "executionSuccess" : true,
  "nReturned" : 0,
  "executionTimeMillis" : 82671,
  "totalKeysExamined" : 1749689,
  "totalDocsExamined" : 1643722,
  "executionStages" : {
   "stage" : "COUNT",
   "nReturned" : 0,
   "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 80960,
   "works" : 1750066,
   "advanced" : 0,
   "needTime" : 1749689,
   "needFetch" : 376,
   "saveState" : 14662,
   "restoreState" : 14662,
   "isEOF" : 1,
   "invalidates" : 0,
   "nCounted" : 1643722,
   "nSkipped" : 0,
   "inputStage" : {
    "stage" : "FETCH",
    "nReturned" : 1643722,
    "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 80890,
    "works" : 1750065,
    "advanced" : 1643722,
    "needTime" : 105967,
    "needFetch" : 376,
    "saveState" : 14662,
    "restoreState" : 14662,
    "isEOF" : 1,
    "invalidates" : 0,
    "docsExamined" : 1643722,
    "alreadyHasObj" : 0,
    "inputStage" : {
     "stage" : "IXSCAN",
     "nReturned" : 1643722,
     "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 3800,
     "works" : 1749689,
     "advanced" : 1643722,
     "needTime" : 105967,
     "needFetch" : 0,
     "saveState" : 14662,
     "restoreState" : 14662,
     "isEOF" : 1,
     "invalidates" : 0,
     "keyPattern" : {
      "createdAt" : -1,
      "status" : -1,
      "oId" : -1
     },
     "indexName" : "moderatedContent",
     "isMultiKey" : false,
     "direction" : "forward",
     "indexBounds" : {
      "createdAt" : [
       "(new Date(1467195213000), new Date(1459246413000)]"
      ],
      "status" : [
       "[\"UNDECIDED\", \"UNDECIDED\"]",
       "[\"APPROVED\", \"APPROVED\"]"
      ],
      "oId" : [
       "[MaxKey, MinKey]"
      ]
     },
     "keysExamined" : 1749689,
     "dupsTested" : 0,
     "dupsDropped" : 0,
     "seenInvalidated" : 0,
     "matchTested" : 0
    }
   }
  },
  "allPlansExecution" : [ ]
 }
```

For find.

```js
"executionStats" : {
  "executionSuccess" : true,
  "nReturned" : 1643722,
  "executionTimeMillis" : 1216,
  "totalKeysExamined" : 1749689,
  "totalDocsExamined" : 0,
  "executionStages" : {
   "stage" : "PROJECTION",
   "nReturned" : 1643722,
   "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 1080,
   "works" : 1749690,
   "advanced" : 1643722,
   "needTime" : 105967,
   "needFetch" : 0,
   "saveState" : 13669,
   "restoreState" : 13669,
   "isEOF" : 1,
   "invalidates" : 0,
   "transformBy" : {
    "_id" : 0,
    "status" : 1
   },
   "inputStage" : {
    "stage" : "IXSCAN",
    "nReturned" : 1643722,
    "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 920,
    "works" : 1749690,
    "advanced" : 1643722,
    "needTime" : 105967,
    "needFetch" : 0,
    "saveState" : 13669,
    "restoreState" : 13669,
    "isEOF" : 1,
    "invalidates" : 0,
    "keyPattern" : {
     "createdAt" : -1,
     "status" : -1,
     "oId" : -1
    },
    "indexName" : "moderatedContent",
    "isMultiKey" : false,
    "direction" : "forward",
    "indexBounds" : {
     "createdAt" : [
      "(new Date(1467195213000), new Date(1459246413000)]"
     ],
     "status" : [
      "[\"UNDECIDED\", \"UNDECIDED\"]",
      "[\"APPROVED\", \"APPROVED\"]"
     ],
     "oId" : [
      "[MaxKey, MinKey]"
     ]
    },
    "keysExamined" : 1749689,
    "dupsTested" : 0,
    "dupsDropped" : 0,
    "seenInvalidated" : 0,
    "matchTested" : 0
   }
  }
 }
```

For post with .explain() first in the cursor:

```js
"executionStats" : {
  "executionSuccess" : true,
  "nReturned" : 0,
  "executionTimeMillis" : 89191,
  "totalKeysExamined" : 1749689,
  "totalDocsExamined" : 1643722,
  "executionStages" : {
   "stage" : "COUNT",
   "nReturned" : 0,
   "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 83400,
   "works" : 1751709,
   "advanced" : 0,
   "needTime" : 1749689,
   "needFetch" : 2019,
   "saveState" : 15648,
   "restoreState" : 15648,
   "isEOF" : 1,
   "invalidates" : 0,
   "nCounted" : 1643722,
   "nSkipped" : 0,
   "inputStage" : {
    "stage" : "FETCH",
    "nReturned" : 1643722,
    "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 83260,
    "works" : 1751708,
    "advanced" : 1643722,
    "needTime" : 105967,
    "needFetch" : 2019,
    "saveState" : 15648,
    "restoreState" : 15648,
    "isEOF" : 1,
    "invalidates" : 0,
    "docsExamined" : 1643722,
    "alreadyHasObj" : 0,
    "inputStage" : {
     "stage" : "IXSCAN",
     "nReturned" : 1643722,
     "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 8290,
     "works" : 1749689,
     "advanced" : 1643722,
     "needTime" : 105967,
     "needFetch" : 0,
     "saveState" : 15648,
     "restoreState" : 15648,
     "isEOF" : 1,
     "invalidates" : 0,
     "keyPattern" : {
      "createdAt" : -1,
      "status" : -1,
      "oId" : -1
     },
     "indexName" : "moderatedContent",
     "isMultiKey" : false,
     "direction" : "forward",
     "indexBounds" : {
      "createdAt" : [
       "(new Date(1467195213000), new Date(1459246413000)]"
      ],
      "status" : [
       "[\"UNDECIDED\", \"UNDECIDED\"]",
       "[\"APPROVED\", \"APPROVED\"]"
      ],
      "oId" : [
       "[MaxKey, MinKey]"
      ]
     },
     "keysExamined" : 1749689,
     "dupsTested" : 0,
     "dupsDropped" : 0,
     "seenInvalidated" : 0,
     "matchTested" : 0
    }
   }
  }
 }
```

Comment: Use the explain method and check what is happening. Can you also post both explain logs?

Comment: @TiagoBértolo posted.

Comment: Something is wrong with your explains. He shouldn't start by the count.

Comment: Can you post the explain of this command ? model.explain().find({createdAt: {'$gte': threeMonths, '$lt': today},status: {'$in': model.STATUS_SET}}).count()

Comment: This one doesn't provide execution stats.

Comment: Oh, wait, it does. But the results are identical to the one I posted.

Comment: Can you post them?

Comment: @TiagoBértolo posted them

Answer (score 4):

Key to your answer is

```
//count
"totalDocsExamined" : 1643722,
```

vs

```
//find
"totalDocsExamined" : 0,
```

The find query operates entirely on the index and does not read any single document while the count query actually reads every document from the db.

The reason is, your find query  uses the `lean()` option. According to mongoose [doc](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-lean):

> Documents returned from queries with the lean option enabled are plain javascript objects, not MongooseDocuments. They have no save method, getters/setters or other Mongoose magic applied.

On top of that, in your lean find query you are only `select()`ing `id` and `status`, which seems to be projected (`"transformBy" ...`) and so the entire query becomes a *[covered query](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/query-optimization/#covered-query)* and no documents must be read to serve the request.

Comment: I understand that. But I can't help wondering if mongo has any way of returning just the size of the cursor once it had finished with the find query?
Besides, does it really take 90 seconds to iterate over the resulting set?

Comment: in mongoshell its just `db.yourCollection.find(...).count()`, in mongoose it seems to be `model.find({query}).select({projection}).lean().count()` - but I haven't tested this... Besides, the estimate is in millis, so it's rather 90 seconds

Comment: What I mean is that if I can retrieve all docs with a covered query in under 3 seconds and then just get the length of the resulting array, then why can't mongo? I mean, I'd even leave it like that, but I just don't have enough RAM for that.

Comment: Covered queries are just very performant when retrieving documents, but you don't need that for counting. I'm not that familiar with mongoose, but I think in your case `find({query})` fetches the documents and `count` runs on the result in mongoose and not mongodb - and therefore profits from `lean()` and covered query.  I assume just `model.count({query})` would execute the count on the mongodb and should be fine.

Comment: I think we have a misunderstanding. What I'm doing is a simple `find(query)` which results in mongodb executing a covered query, and then all I have to do is retrieve the `.length` property of the resulting array. ~3 seconds, but extremely taxing due to 1.6 million records being fetched.
If I'm doing a `find(query).count()`, no matter if in mongoose or in mongodb, it takes around ~90 seconds. What I can't grasp is, why isn't it possible for mongo to simply return the '.length' on the server side? It's clear I'm missing some vital point, but I'm not sure what that point is.

Comment: as Clement Amarnath pointed out, in mongo, `count` will do a `find(query).count()`, without a projection, it will fetch all matching documents without profiting from a covered query. If you do a `find({query},{projection}).count()` the execution speed may profit from covered query. I don't know the internals of mongoose and how the query operations will map to mongo commands, but apparently `lean()` seems to have an effect.

Answer (score 2):

Find - Finds documents in a collection and returns a cursor to the selected documents. Cursor is a pointer to the result set of a query. Clients can iterate through a cursor to retrieve results.

Count - count() is equivalent to the `db.collection.find(query).count()`

Count is actually a cursor method, the shell simply provides a shortcut. in Shell we have shortcut for count as shown here `db.collection.count(query)`

Reason: In find operation we are not iterating over the result set, whereas in count operation we are doing an operation on the result set. That would cause the time delay.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.count/

Comment: So there's no way to avoid this iteration?

Comment: @nainy -  Added some more info on the answer. Hope it will clarify your query.